# how to query data inside an array of the collection using mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a mongoose schema like this :

```
 var LogsSchema = new Schema({
    date: Date,
    longitude: String,
    latitude: String,
    speed: Number
 });

var DeviceSchema = new Schema({

name: String,
model: String,
phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
push: Number,   
logs: [LogsSchema],
})
```

i have huge array of logs in my database how can i sort limit and skip  **logs array data** ??
currently i am taking only last 10 elements of array but i want to select applying condition .  Using $elemMatch doesnot solve my problem it shows from whole collection but i need from individual documents.
what is wish is to find logs from date range. 
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example query that you have tried and what your expected output is with some sample documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use aggregation framework.$unwind your log array and apply whatever condition you want $sort $match,skip.or you can check $filter in $project stage,please post your expected output I will try my hand

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$unwind" : "$logs"},
{$match : {"$and" :  [{"logs.date" :{$gte : fromDate} },
{"logs.date" :{"$lte" : toDate}}]}},
{"$group" : "_id" : "_id",
"logs" : {"$push" : "$logs"},
"names" :{"$first" : "$name"}
}])
```

Or you can use $filter if using mongodb 3.2

```
{
  $filter: {
     input: logs,
     as: "num",
     cond: { $and: [
        { $gte: [ "$$num.date", fromDate ] },
        { $lte: [ "$$num.date", toDate ] }
      ] }
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to fetch logs from  $gte:"a_date", $lte:"a_date"