# Trouble filtering dates in nested array to match query Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have build the following project for FreecodeCamp.
My project has to save users name and exercise and time to compete(which includes a date).
My problem is accessing the collective data array of dates and only returning dates and exercises matching query in url.
Here is my JSON code returned. I need only a set limit dates and exercises matching query set by user's query in url to return amount of dates matching `2018-11-22T00:00:00.000Z` (example `localhost:3000/addme16?id=5_OYzu1QG&start=22 November 2018&end=22 November 2018&limit=2`). Thus returning only two date objects matching 2018-11-22T00:00:00.000Z if query limit is set to two dates and exercises to be returned.

```js
{
    "_id": "5_OYzu1QG",
    "username": "Timmy",
    "data": [{
            "description": "walking",
            "duration": 1,
            "date": "2018-11-22T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "description": "Reading",
            "duration": 2,
            "date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "description": "Mountain Biking",
            "duration": 3,
            "date": "2019-01-22T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I forgot to add my schema and my method of changing query string dates to iso object date. Here is my extra code information that show how i add a exercise to my users data. I only want to return the dates that match iso data query dates in database

```js
//my schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const mySchema = new Schema ({
  _id:String,
  username: String,
  data: [{
 _id:false,  
    description : String,
    duration: Number,
    date :{type:Date}
  }]
});

const ExampleClass = mongoose.model('array',mySchema);

module.exports = ExampleClass;

//Save and create new user with id in array collection in mongodb
app.post('/api/exercise/new-user',(req, res)=>{
   let myTest = req.body.user.myName;
   let testing = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/
   if(testing.test(myTest) === true && myTest !== ""){
   
        array.find({username:req.body.user.myName}) 
       .then(user => {
  if (user.length !== 0) {
   return res.send({error:"Name already exists in database"});
        } 
  if(user.length === 0){
   
   myId = shortid.generate();
   let data = new array({
    
          username:req.body.user.myName,
    _id:myId,
             })
    
   data.save(user,err=>{   
  if(err) throw err;
  return res.send({
      username:req.body.user.myName,
         _id:myId
                 });
 
 });
 
  }

    }).catch(err => {
 
         if(err) throw err;
  
    });
   }else{
  res.send({username:"Invalid name! Please enter a string of letters for name."})  
   }
 
});


//adding exercise to user data
app.post('/api/exercise/add',(req,res)=>{
 let myTest = req.body.user.userTask;
 const testing = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/
 const myNum =  /^\d+$/;
 const space = /^\s+$/;
 const checker = /^[0-9-]*$/
 let checking = req.body.user.userDuration;
 
 array.countDocuments({_id:req.body.user.userId},(err, count)=>{
 if(count>0){
  if(testing.test(myTest) === true && myTest !== ""){
   if(myNum.test(checking)=== true){
    let inPutDate;
          let timestamp;
          let d;
    if(Object.keys(req.body.user.userDate).length === 0){
     let date1 = Date.now();
           date1 = new Date(date1);
                 date1.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
    array.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.user.userId},{ $push :{data:{ description : req.body.user.userTask, duration :Number(req.body.user.userDuration),date:date1}}},{new:true}).then((data)=>{
       date1 = new Date(date1).toDateString();
       console.log(data)
       res.send({ 
             username:data.username,
             date:date1,
             description:req.body.user.userTask,
          duration:Number(req.body.user.userDuration),
          _id:req.body.user.userId
       })
    }).catch(err => {
 
         if(err) throw err;
  
    }); 
    }else{
     
     timestamp = new Date(req.body.user.userDate);
     d = moment(timestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000") + "Z";
     inPutDate = new Date(d);
     let checking = d;
     console.log(inPutDate)
     console.log(typeof(inPutDate))
    array.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.user.userId},{ $push :{data:{ description : req.body.user.userTask, duration :Number(req.body.user.userDuration),date:inPutDate}}},{new:true}).then((data)=>{
       inPutDate = new Date(inPutDate).toDateString();
       console.log(data)
       res.send({ 
             username:data.username,
             date:inPutDate,
             description:req.body.user.userTask,
          duration:Number(req.body.user.userDuration),
          _id:req.body.user.userId
       })
    }).catch(err => {
 
         if(err) throw err;
  
    }); 
    
    
    
    }
    }else{
  res.send({duration:"Please type a number value"})
 } 
   }else{
  res.send({description:"Invalid description! Please enter a string of letters for description."})  
   }
  }else{
     res.send({_id:"Please type correct id from datbase"})
    }
 });  
})

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to set a limit on matching date or dates of document. I am including following code.

```js
app.get('/api/exercise/log',(req,res)=>{
 array.findById({_id:req.query.id},(err,data)=>{
  let iniate = new Date(req.query.start);
     let one = moment(iniate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000") + "Z";
     let date1 = new Date(one);
     console.log(date1);
     console.log(typeof(date1));
 let iniate1 = new Date(req.query.end);
     let two = moment(iniate1).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000") + "Z";
     let date2 = new Date(two);
     console.log(date2)
     console.log(typeof(date2)) 
  let myLength;
    if(req.query.start === undefined && req.query.end === undefined && req.query.limit === undefined && req.query.id !== undefined){
   myLength = data.data.length;
  array.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id: req.query.id}}]).then(data =>{
  res.send({count:myLength,data})
 })
   }
   else if(req.query.start !== undefined && req.query.end !== undefined && req.query.limit !== undefined && req.query.id !== undefined){
   array.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id: req.query.id}},
    { $unwind: '$data'},{$match : {"$and" :  [{"data.date" :{$gte : date1} },
    {"data.date" :{"$lte" : date2}}]}}]).limit(Number(req.query.limit)).then(data =>{
  if(data.length >= Number(req.query.limit)){
  res.send(data)
  }else{
  return  res.send({error:"Document do not match limit requested"})
   }
 })
   }
  })
})
```

This finally returned required parameters of project , which was needed to complete my project for Free Code Camp. Using following link[how to query data inside an array of the collection using mongoose

[how to query data inside an array of the collection using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703257/) stackoverflow how-to-query-data-inside-an-array-of-the-collection-using-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Given the url string: 
`2018-11-22T00:00:00.000Z (example localhost:3000/addme16?id=5_OYzu1QG&start=22 November 2018&end=22 November 2018&limit=2)`

Extract the year, month and day then:

```
const data = db.Collection.find({
        date: {
            "created_on": {
                "$gte": new Date(2018, 11, 22),
                "$lt": new Date(2018, 11, 23)
            }
        }
    }).limit(2)
```

The use of `$gte` (greater than equal) and `$lt` (less than the next day) ensure you get all timestamps of that day